# How to find clusters a matrix

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I have no clue about data mining or data analysis or statistical analysis but I think what I need is finding "clusters in a matrix". I have a data set of ~20k records and each has ~40 characteristics all of which are either turned on or off.

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| record | hasA | hasB | hasC | hasD | hasE | hasF |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| foo    |    1 |    0 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
| bar    |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    1 |    1 |
| baz    |    1 |    1 |    1 |    0 |    0 |    0 |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

I'm quite convinced most of those 20k records have characteristics that fall into one of several categories. There must be means to determine how similar record 'foo' is to record 'bar'.

So, what is it that I'm actually looking at? What algorithm am I looking for?

Comment: Are all characteristics 0/1 values?

Comment: This might be a better question for [stats.se].

Comment: @blazs yes, by "turned on or off" I meant 1/0, sorry. Just as you figured in the first sentence of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Transform each record `r` into a binary vector `v(r)` so that `i`-th component of `v(r)` is set to `1` if `r` has `i`-th characteristic, and `0` otherwise.

Now run [hierarchical clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) algorithm on this set of vectors under the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), whichever you think is more appropriate; also make sure there's a notion of distance between clusters defined in terms of the underlying distance (see [linkage criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria)).

Then decide where to cut the resulting [dendrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) based on common sense. Where you cut the dendrogram will affect the number of clusters.

One downside of hierarchical clustering is that it's rather slow. It takes `O(n^3)` time in general, so it would take quite a while on a large data set. For single- and complete-linkages you can bring the time down to `O(n^2)`.

Hierarchical clustering is very easy to implement in languages such as Python. You can also use the implementation from the `scipy` library.

### Example: Hierarchical Clustering in Python

Here's a code snippet to get you started. I assume `S` is the set of records transformed into binary vectors (i.e. each list in `S` corresponds to a record from your data set).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# This is the set of binary vectors, each of which would
# correspond to a record in your case.
S = [
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], # 0
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1], # 1
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0], # 2
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0], # 3
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], # 4
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]] # 5

# Use Hamming distance with complete linkage.
Z = sch.linkage(sch.distance.pdist(S, metric='hamming'), 'complete')

# Compute the dendrogram
P = sch.dendrogram(Z)

plt.show()
```

The result is as you'd expect: cut at 0.5 to get two clusters, one of the first three vectors (which have ones at beginning, zeros at the end) and the other of the last three vectors (which have ones at the end, zeros at the beginning). Here's the image:

[image]

Hierarchical clustering starts with each vector being its own cluster. In each successive steps it merges the closest clusters. It repeats this until there is a single cluster left.

The dendrogram essentially encodes the whole clustering process. At the beginning each vector is its own cluster. Then `{3}` and `{5}` merge into `{3,5}` and `{0}` and `{2}` merge into `{0,2`}. Next, `{4}` and `{3,5}` merge into `{3,4,5}`, and `{1}` and `{0,2}` merge into `{0,1,2}`. Finally, `{0,1,2}` and `{3,4,5}` merge into `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`.

From the dendrogram you can usually see at which point it makes the most sense to cut---this will define your clusters.

I encourage you to experiment with various distances (e.g. Hamming distance, Jaccard distance) and linkages (e.g. single linkage, complete linkage), and various representations (e.g. binary vectors).

Comment: Thanks, enough food for thought and reading, looks like my gut feeling wasn't completely off.

Comment: @MarcelStör no problem. I provided a simple code that works and can be readily used once you transform your data into the form o `S` above.

Comment: This will barely scale to 20k instances, yet more if the OP ever increases his data set size. But in the end, he might not need clustering at all - but simply similarity search.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want cluster analysis?

To **find similar records** you don't need cluster analysis. Simply find similar records with any distance measure such as Jaccard similarity or Hamming distance (both of which are for binary data). Or cosine distance, so that you can use e.g. Lucene to find similar records fast.

To find **common patterns**, the use of *frequent itemset mining* may yield much more meaningful results, because these can work on a subset of attributes only. For example, in a supermarket, the columns Noodles, Tomato, Basil, Cheese may constitute a frequent pattern.

Most clustering algorithms attempt to divide the data into k groups. While this at first appears a good idea (get k target groups) it rarely matches what real data contains. For example customers: why would every customer belong to exactly one audience? What if the audiences are e.g. car lovers, gun lovers, football lovers, soccer moms - are you sure you don't want to allow overlap of these groups?
Furhermore, a problem with cluster analysis is that it's incredibly easy to use badly. It does not "fail hard" - you always get a result, and you might not realize that it's a bad result...

Comment: "Simply find similar records with any distance measure such as Jaccard similarity or Hamming distance" this is evident from the dendrogram.

Comment: Regarding a bad result, the user should always get her hands dirty to see what the data "looks like" (e.g. run preliminary computations) and whether the results make sense. If not, she should change representation/change distance function/etc. (using common sense).

Comment: Frequent itemset mining (e.g [association rule learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning)) might be a good idea in this case.

Comment: You don't need a dendrogram (which scales to a few dozen instances only) to find similar objects. In fact, you first need to find similar object to be able to do hierarchical clustering at all.

Comment: I know how the hierarchical clustering works. I am now thinking he should use locality sensitive hashing.

Comment: You don't need LSH for this kind of data.

Comment: It scales much better than frequent itemset mining; I don't recall what the time complexity of association rule learning is, but when I used it several years ago, it took a long time (though my implementation was certainly not the best possible).

Comment: APRIORI is O(n*l) where l is the pattern length. But it's easy to implement badly. Hierarchical clustering is O(n^3).